# Maven 3 plugin: List dependencies of project

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to create a maven 3 plugin that should parse every dependency and transitive dependency of the project, and list the artifacts, preferably with a link to the jar file in the local maven repo. I am not having much luck.

I have to treat the dependencies afterwards, to the dependency and tree plugins are not really an option for me. I need to create a custom plugin which can work on the dependency artifacts.

I have tried creating a plugin using the DependencyGraphBuilder with exactly no success:

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project.build.directory}", property = "outputDir", required = true)
private File outputDirectory;

@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
private MavenProject project;

@Parameter(defaultValue = "${session}", readonly = true, required = true)
private MavenSession session;

@Component(hint = "maven3")
private DependencyGraphBuilder dependencyGraphBuilder;

@Override
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    File targetDir = outputDirectory;

    if (!targetDir.exists()) {
        targetDir.mkdirs();
    }

    ProjectBuildingRequest buildingRequest = new DefaultProjectBuildingRequest(session.getProjectBuildingRequest());
    buildingRequest.setProject(project);
    try {
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(outputDirectory, "output"))) {
            writer.println("I did shit");
        }

        DependencyNode depenGraphRootNode = dependencyGraphBuilder.buildDependencyGraph(buildingRequest, null);
        CollectingDependencyNodeVisitor visitor = new CollectingDependencyNodeVisitor();
        depenGraphRootNode.accept(visitor);
        List<DependencyNode> children = visitor.getNodes();
        for (DependencyNode node : children) {
            System.out.println(node.getArtifact().getGroupId() + " " + node.getArtifact().getArtifactId());
            try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(outputDirectory, "output"))) {
                writer.println(node.getArtifact().getGroupId() + " " + node.getArtifact().getArtifactId());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

I have gotten a few different exceptions, depending on the depenency versions in my pom, for example

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.artifact.versioning.DefaultArtifactVersion.compareTo(Lorg/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ArtifactVersion;)I

and

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/aether/RepositorySystemSession

Could someone please provide me with a working dependency setup for making the DependencyGraphBuilder work, or alternatively, a different way of parsing the compiling projects dependencies?

Comment: Are you trying to create https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html?

Comment: No i need to do some work on the dependencies afterwards, which is why i need to get the path to the artifacts as well